# Is there a property in gridview to show record numbers on the left side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv_list_recs"  
        Width="100%"
        BorderStyle="none"
        GridLines="horizontal" 
        AutoGenerateColumns ="false" PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_list_recs_PageIndexChanging"
        DataKeyNames = "SI_Form_ID"  RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
        CellPadding="2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#e2e2e2"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_header" HorizontalAlign="Center"
        runat="server">
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="5"  FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Position="TopAndBottom" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle Height="150px" HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#031D40" Font-Bold="True"/>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Form_ID" HeaderText="Form ID">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign ="Left" CssClass="alternative_grid" Font-Size="10" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="60px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
.
.
.
```

Basically, I have around 85 records and I would like to see a record number on the left when paging through it. Is there a property in gridview for that or do I code it in sql? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://asp.net-informations.com/gridview/row-number.htm

Comment: Thank you, OldProgrammer!! That works well!!